# Does setting default pages for sub directories improve seo?

Tags: seo, 403-forbidden

I noticed 403 errors on sub directories of my site while looking over google webmaster tools.

for example .com/reviews/ has a 403 error.

I set the default pages for the sub directories (pointed to the primary page in the directory). I believe this will solve the 403 issue (if I am wrong please let me know).

However I am wondering if this has any effect for SEO purposes ?
Does google penalize for these 403 errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you have links to the URLs that are returning a 403 error then you will leak whatever Page Rank that is being sent to that URL.  Since Google is finding these 403 errors I assume something is linking to the URLs that are returning 403s.

However, unless it is your home page, it isn't going to be a huge SEO problem or loss of PR.  Another good reason to fix something like this is that it creates a better experience for your users when they find a way to navigate to the pages that are currently returning 403 errors.