# Do subdirectory URLs need to work for SEO if there are other URLs within that subdirectory? Does time of indexing subdirectory matter in search result

Tags: seo, url, search-engine-indexing, subdirectory, directory-index

I have a website where I built a sub-folder structure on my links, like this: `/category/city/postname`

Does it matter if `/category/city` doesn't have a page, even if there is no link to it on the entire website?

If I build a page for `/category/city` now, could this page climb higher than `/category/city/postname` in search results, since first page index after second page already have been indexed by search engine?

To clarify we want combination of two words "category" and "city" in search results bring up `/category/city` before `/category/city/postname` 
**even if `/category/city` is indexed after `/category/city/postname` over time**

Comment: See also: [A top directory in a URL path returns a 404 error, will its subpages still be crawled?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/105612/a-top-directory-in-a-url-path-returns-a-404-error-will-its-subpages-still-be-cr) and [Does setting default pages for sub directories improve seo?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26074/does-setting-default-pages-for-sub-directories-improve-seo)

Comment: This only answers part one, part two still remains unanswered.